# Float left is behaving like float right

Tags: html, css

I'm floating a bunch of images that I want to appear in a gallery. They should just appear in neat rows. They're all the same size, so I figured I could do this by just floating all of the li's of a ul left and setting them to "`display: block;`."

Instead, they're doing this: http://packardcarbs.myshopify.com/products/standard-8-1929-1931

The password is "ataska"

Comment: So, exactly what is wrong?  Your images seem to be laid out fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all of the images are the same height. In the first row, your first image is 149px high and the next two are 146px high. So when you break down to your next row, the images will start 3px up and to the left of your original first image. If you want them to line up correctly in a nice grid, you need to make sure that they all have the same height.

Applying a `height: 160px` to all list items solves the problem (your tallest image is 160px high).

Answer (score 0):

I removed the margin-right: 20 and things lined up nicely.

Comment: This is only coincidence because the last image in each row happens to be the tallest image.

Answer (score 0):

remove the margins and it'll line up...

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you added margin right and then 4th item does not fit inside the `ul`, if you need margin you will need a for loop or something and then add class to the 4th element like `margin:0`. Or just reduce `margin-right:15px` and it will all fit.

Answer (score 0):

from what i see you could also do this:

```
ul#thumbs li a {
   display:block;
   width:160px;
   height:160px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

This way the images will align no matter the height (a part of them will be hidden if higher than `160px;`)

Also, you have a `margin-right` of `12.5px` on the `li` element. (not too nice using it), you can make it `15 px` without any problems.